# How to parse user defined html attributes using html DOM with '-' in that attribute?

Tags: php, html, simple-html-dom, user-defined

For example:

```html
$html = "<div title='test a' class='a' classes='testing custom attribute with -' >test a</div>
         <div title='test b' class='b' >test b</div>
         <div title='test c' class='c' >test c</div>";

$htmldom = str_get_html($html);
$ab = $htmldom->find("div[class=a]");
foreach($ab as $e){
 echo $e->classes;
}
```

This gives me response like: "***testing custom attribute with -***"

But when i place '-' in custom attribute, like:

```html
$html = "<div title='test a' class='a' class-es='testing custom attribute with -' >test first</div>
         <div title='test b' class='b' >test b</div>
         <div title='test c' class='c' >test c</div>";

$htmldom = str_get_html($html);
$div_a = $htmldom->find("div[class=a]");
foreach($div_a as $e){
 echo $e->class-es;
}
```

This is responding with an error:

***"Notice: Use of undefined constant es - assumed 'es' in E:..."***

Any help will be appreciated... Thanks in advance.

Comment: What programming language are you using? Please tag the question appropriately.

Comment: @JukkaK.Korpela Looks like PHP

Comment: Yup its PHP... it is tagged... sorry for inconvenience...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Seems php. http://php.net/manual/en/sdo.sample.getset.php

Don't use object property access syntax, use the array index way: $e['class-es']
(...and maybe ->{'class-es'} could also work)